# How to secure Audience and Issure in JWT Token as they are validated at time authorization yet available in claims which are prone to be hacked easily

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, jwt

I'm trying to issue the authentication token using JWT in .net core application. I have read the documentation available at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519

I am signing my token either with HmacSha256Signature or with certificate. both Audience and Issuers are also being provided at time of generating the token and I'm validating it at time of authorization. As per are https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519, both of these are added in the token as claim which makes them readable and available to hackers to play with; as they can easily be decrypted, read and retrieved from the token and if it is so then:

**how it is secured then? Some one may generate a false token using the same audience and issuer value which was used in code. Authentication will approve it as its a simple text comparison values would be same?**

*One thing, which I have done to secure it is; I have fetched the URI from httpcontext and used it as audience and time of generating the token and comparing it at time of authentication with the static expected value and its working fine.*

but I'm worried about:

1. What step we may take to ensure that our token is secured and can not be hacked or cypher?
2. Is signing the token make it much secure to keep this information publicly accessible?
3. Can JWT automatically identify its target audience and secure it?
4. Can we use encryption to secure it and decrypt the information at time of authentication?
5. Any other advice to make it secure?

**Token Generator:**

```
        public string GenerateSecurityToken(string email)

        {

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();


            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor

            {

                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]

            {

                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email)

                }),

                Issuer = _jwtSettings.Value.Issuer, // static text from config

                Audience = _jwtSettings.Value.Audience, // base url from http context

                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_jwtSettings.Value.ExpirationInMinutes),

                SigningCredentials = this.getSigningCredentials(),

                IssuedAt = DateTime.Now

            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            var strToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return strToken;

        }
```

**Authentication:**

```
        private static TokenValidationParameters GetX509BasedParameters(IConfiguration config)

        {

            var issuer = config.GetSection("JwtConfig").GetSection("issuer").Value;

            var audience = config.GetSection("JwtConfig").GetSection("audience").Value;

            var pfxFilename = config.GetSection("JwtConfig").GetSection("securityFile").Value;

            X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(pfxFilename, "");

            X509SecurityKey x509Key = new X509SecurityKey(x509);


            return new TokenValidationParameters

            {

                ValidateIssuer = true,

                ValidateAudience = true,

                ValidIssuer = issuer,

                ValidAudience = audience,

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                RequireExpirationTime = true,

                IssuerSigningKey = x509Key,

            };

        }
```

Comment: When your issuer validates the token, it checks if the signature is valid using a key that is only known to the issuer self. So someone that knows what data to put in the token, should also know the private signing key. When you trust a certain issuer, you add it to your valid issuer configuration. If an issuer exposed a key, you should remove it from your valid issuer list until the issuer has resolved the issue.

Comment: See para 12 of RFC7519.  Using TLS security at version 1.2 or newer will make the token secure.

Comment: @Silvermind - my concern is if someone knows what valid data they need to put in the token how exactly jwt is comparing it then to make it invalid. its simple string comparison. private signing key is to sign the token how its going to make sure that data is not valid?

Comment: @jdweng - I'm using certificate pfx file for signing the token, but how will it secure the token when its simple string comparison.

Comment: I'm actually intrested in understanding the mechanism how jwt actually perform the authentication when the token claims are simple string comparison? What step I may take to minimize the chances of cracking the token.

Comment: It is not a simple string comparison.  It is using Cryptographic methods.  there is a public and private key.  The certificate needs to be installed on bot client and server to get private key.  The signing is adding a public key to the document.  So the validation is checking the xml file to see that it matches the signing key (including the private key)

Comment: @AliMamoon The data is combined with the key to generate a signature. So if any of the data is changed, the signature will not be valid.

Comment: So means, it would be safe to use it the way i'm already doing it?